# How to start mupad from matlab?

Tags: matlab, mupad

I want to plot inequalities. Mupad is very useful in doing that. How is it possible to start Mupad from Matlab ?
Using `mphandle = mupad` returns error `??? Undefined function or variable 'mupad'.`
I am using matlab version `7.11.0.584 (R2010b)`

Comment: Are you sure that you have MuPAD, which is an optional extra for Matlab, installed ?  If you do have it installed, why can't you answer this question for yourself from the generally very good documentation that the Mathworks publish by the tonne ?

Comment: I was not sure, answer below helped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mupad` is a part of the `Symbolic Math Toolbox`(http://www.mathworks.de/products/symbolic/). Check if you have it using the command `ver`

Comment: using `ver` returns list of packages which does not mention `mupad` anywhere. this means mupad is not there . right ?

Comment: it should mention Symbolic Math Toolbox. If it doesnt mention that, you need to buy that toolbox from mathworks.

Comment: it does not, so i dont have mupad, thanks for help. You may help me here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385063/easiest-way-to-plot-inequalities-with-hatched-fill