# General issues regarding a plot

Tags: r, plot

Using `R` , I have drawn a hatched plot similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385063/easiest-way-to-plot-inequalities-with-hatched-fill). I want to do following 4 things in `R`

1. Add legend as shown in the link.
2. Replace x-axis name by the greek symbol of delta
3. To mention various points of intersection on the plot. for eg, at x=0.75 a few curves meet x-axis, I want to put the value `0.75` near that point.
4. If you see the curves, they are not smooth. How to make them smooth ? Even excel plots far more smoother curves.

How to achieve this ?

Here is the plot.

[image: plot]

Following code is used to draw the plot.

```
plot(NA,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1),xlab="delta",ylab="K", xaxs="i",yaxs="i") # Empty plot
a1 <- curve((x+x^7-x^2-x^4)/(1+x-x^3-x^4), from=0, n=450000, add = TRUE) # First curve
a2 <- curve((x^2+x^3-x-x^5)/(x+x^2), to=0.9, n=45000, add = TRUE)
a3 <- curve((x+x^7-x^2-x^4)/(1+x-x^2-x^3-x^4+x^7),from=0, n=45000, add = TRUE)
a4 <- curve((x+x^8-x^3-x^5)/(x+x^8-x^3-x^5+1-x^4),from=0, to=0.9, n=45000, add = TRUE)
a5 <- curve((x+x^8-x^3-x^5)/(1+x-x^5-x^4),from=0, n=45000, add = TRUE)
a6 <- curve((x+x^2-x^4-1)/(x-x^4), to=0.84, n=45000, add = TRUE)
a7 <- curve((x+x^6-x^3-x^4)/(1+x-x^3-x^4), from=0.83 ,to=1,  n=45000, add = TRUE)
a8 <- curve((1+x^7-x^2-x^4)/(1+x^3-x-x^4), from=0.819, n=45000, add = TRUE)
a9 <- curve((x)/(1+x), n=45000,from=0.819, to =1, add = TRUE)


names(a1) <- c('xA1','yA1')
names(a2) <- c('xA2','yA2')
names(a3) <- c('xA3','yA3')
names(a4) <- c('xA4','yA4')
names(a5) <- c('xA5','yA5')
names(a6) <- c('xA6','yA6')
names(a7) <- c('xA7','yA7')
names(a8) <- c('xA8','yA8')
names(a9) <- c('xA9','yA9')


with(as.list(c(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9)),{

idA <- yA3 >=0
idB <- yA2 >=0 & yA2 <= yA4
idC <- yA4 >= yA2

idD <- yA5 >=0

idE <- yA6 >=0 & yA6 <= yA7
idF <- yA7 <= yA6

idG <- yA8 >=0 & yA8 <= yA9 
idH <- xA9 >= xA8 &  xA9 >0.8

idI <- xA1 >=0 & xA1 <= 0.755
idJ <- xA3 >=0 & xA3 <= 0.755



 polygon(x = c(xA3[idA],xA2[idB],rev(xA4[idC])),
        y = c(yA3[idA],yA2[idB],rev(yA4[idC])), 
        density=20, angle=90, border=NULL)

 polygon(x = c(xA5[idD],1,1,0),
        y = c(yA5[idD],0,1,1), 
        density=20, angle=0, border=NULL)

 polygon(x = c(xA6,xA7),
        y = c(yA6,yA7), 
        density=20, angle=45, border=NULL)

 polygon(x = c(rev(xA8[idG]),xA9[idH],1),
        y = c(rev(yA8[idG]),yA9[idH],0), 
        density=20, angle=135, border=NULL)

 polygon(x = c(xA1[idI],rev(xA3[idJ])),
        y = c(yA1[idI],rev(yA3[idJ])), 
        col="black", border=NULL)


 })
```

Comment: You can't seriously expect an answer from posting this? Add some details of how you have plotted your graphic. How to add the legend will differ depending on what you use to plot your graph (lattice , grid , base etc)

Comment: Why didn't you add it to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385063/easiest-way-to-plot-inequalities-with-hatched-fill

Comment: Great edit and nice graph. +1 for a clear, reproducible question. In future, consider framing all your questions in this manner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2),nrow=1),
       width=c(4,1)) #Divide your plotting region in two inequal part
par(mar=c(5,4,4,0)) #Get rid of the margin on the right side
plot(NA,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1),
     xlab=expression(delta),ylab="K", xaxs="i",yaxs="i") # Here's your delta
a1 <- curve((x+x^7-x^2-x^4)/(1+x-x^3-x^4), from=0, n=450000, add = TRUE)

...

par(mar=c(5,0,4,2)) #No margin on the left side
plot(c(0,1),type="n", axes=F, xlab="", ylab="") #Empty plot
legend("top",legend=c("1","2","3","4","5"), 
       density=c(20,20,20,20,NA), angle=c(90,0,45,135,NA), 
       col=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"black"), bty="n", cex=1.5)
```

[image]

As for the point you want to label, either use function `text` (or `mtext`) to do it "programmaticaly" or `locator` to do it interactively.

**Edit**: Alternatively (as I said in the comments), this would work as well to put your legend outside the plot area and is probably simpler:

```
par(mar=c(5,4,4,8))
plot(NA,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1),
     xlab=expression(delta),ylab="K", xaxs="i",yaxs="i") # Here's your delta
     a1 <- curve((x+x^7-x^2-x^4)/(1+x-x^3-x^4), from=0, n=450000, add = TRUE)

...

legend(1,1,legend=c("1","2","3","4","5"), 
   density=c(20,20,20,20,NA), angle=c(90,0,45,135,NA), 
   col=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"black"), bty="n", cex=1.5, xpd=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! An alternative to using `layout` here might have been to increase the right margin (say `par(mar=c(5,4,4,8))`) and plot the legend outside using argument `xpd=TRUE`: `legend(1,1,legend=..., xpd=TRUE)`

Comment: Actually I think I'm gonna change my answer to that, because it s a way simpler solution.

Comment: @plannapus is it possible to write the legend `left to right` , because i want to put it below the plot

Comment: @AshniGoyal yes with parameter `horiz=TRUE` (see `?legend`)

Comment: @plannapus why  are graphs not smooth even after using very high `n` in the `curve` ?

Comment: @AshniGoyal I think you'll have to ask a new separate question for that precise point: I might be wrong but i don't think it has to do with the actual "plot-making" process but with the device itself.

Comment: @plannapus I used `mtext("B",4)` , but it places `B` in horizontal orientation. How to control the orientation and change it to vertical one.

Comment: @AshniGoyal `mtext("B", 4, las=2)`

Comment: For question 4 , follow here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447622/how-to-plot-smoother-curves-in-r

Answer (score 8):

The traditional graphics system provides the legend() function for adding a
legend or key to a plot. The legend is usually drawn within the plot region,
and is located relative to user coordinates.

The function has many arguments, here we need to use **angle** and **density** arguments to differentiate hashed regions.

```
legend(0.5, 0.8, paste("region", 1:5),
       density=c(20,20,20,20,0),
       angle=c(90,0,45,135,0))
```

[image]

Comment: that was fast. how to add black region to the legend ? also, how to put legend beyond the plot area ?

Comment: preferably at bottom, otherwise right . also is it possible to write the legend `left to right` instaed of `top to bottom` ?

Comment: @AshniGoyal I will nearly the same solution than plannapus one.